# live update with onblur AND onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, auto-update

Hi I have jQuery ajax calls update user information as soon as the user is finished making changes to textareas on the page. Right now I have it update onblur but I would like to also make sure that the onchange event has been registered so that I know that they didin't just click into and exit the textarea. Is there a good way to combine onblur and onchange for this type of validation?

This is what I have right now:

```
$('#formTitle').bind('blur', function() {
    updateTitle(this.value)
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [`.bind()` - Multiple Events](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: You should only need the `onchange` event. It will only be triggered when the field is blurred.

Comment: No, `onchange` will be triggered if input type=date, even though it's not blurred!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think method .change will be enough.

```
$('#formTitle').change(function() {
    updateTitle(this.value)
});
```

This is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JQa9n/)

Comment: thanks Ivan and Shmiddty... This method only updates after the field is changed and blurred and seems the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this, save the value on focus, and then on blur check to see if it has changed.

```
var save_str = $('#formTitle').val();

$('#formTitle').bind('focus', function() {
  save_str = $(this).val();
});

$('#formTitle').bind('blur', function() {
  if (save_str != $(this).val()) {
    // do something
  }
});
```